# How to submit both data from an input element and an array of Ids from a JSP function?

Tags: jquery, css, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm new to web development and learning the most as "I go along". I'm using  Spring-MVC for the server side and JSP, JQuery and CSS for client side. Up until now I have a simple page that contains 2 time-pickers (jquery) and a list of `<div>s` each contains item data and a check box. When clicked the submit button the whole data was submitted as a form and received as `@RequestParam-s` in my `Controller`. In my next step I wanted each `<div>` to have a functionality as a checkbox: I implemented a `toggle` function that changes the `<div>` background and collects the relevant Ids. Now my question is how do I submit this data to the server (time-picker and array of Ids)? Do I need to build a `JSON` object and submit it? Can I have an example of how to retrieve the var array data from the `toggle` function and the time from the `input element`?
Here is a snippet from my html:

```
<div class="container" >
    <label class="TimeLabel" >Start:</label>
    <input type="text" style="width: 3em;" id="timepicker_start" name="timepicker_start" value="09:00" />
    <label class="TimeLabel">End:</label>
    <input type="text" style="width: 3em;" id="timepicker_end" name="timepicker_end" value="18:00" />
<div/>
...
<!-- item only list -->     
<div class="container">
  <ul class="plainList">
    <c:forEach items="${itemsFrom.itemsOnly}" var="item" varStatus="status">            
      <li>
        <div class="inner">
          <img src="resources/images/${item.id}.png">           
          <ul class="plainList">             
            <li><h4>${item.title} &trade;</h4></li>              
            <li><h5>${item.description}</h5></li>            
          </ul>              
          <div style="clear: both"></div>           
        </div>           
      </li>         
    </c:forEach>      
  </ul>     
</div>
```

and my function:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var count = 0;
    var attrIds = new Array();
    $(function() {
        $(".inner").toggle(function() {
            $(this).css("background", "#2E8B57");
            attrIds.push(this.id);
            count++;
            $("section").find("#attrCount").text(count);
        }, function() {
            $(this).css("background", "#dcdcdc");
            attrIds.splice($.inArray(this.id, attrIds),1);
            count--;
            $("section").find("#attrCount").text(count);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so what I did is created an hidden element:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var hidden = document.createElement("input");
        hidden.type = "hidden";
        hidden.name = "itemsIds";
        hidden.id = "itemsIds";
        document.forms[0].appendChild(hidden);
    });
</script>
```

And in my `Toggle` function I added:

```
            var hid = document.getElementById("itemsIds");
        hid.value = attrIdsArr;
```

Now when I submit my form the `itemsIds` are submitted.
If anyone has any comments regarding my solution and its efficiency I would be happy to get them.